# python - instantiate classes by looping through a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I'm quite new to Python, but come from a Lua background. I know exactly how I would achieve this in lua. I'm sure the answer already exists but I don't know how to ask the question - what terminology to search for? Things like 'dynamically define variables' return a lot of arguments, along with advice to use dictionaries as that is what they are for. But in my case dictionaries don't seem to work.

A condensed example, where Button(ID) is creating an instance of a button class:

```
Button1 = Button(8)
Button2 = Button(3)
Button3 = Button(432)
ButtonClose = Button(5004)
```

As there are more than 4 buttons in my actual UI, and I do more with them than just instantiate the class objects, I wish to use a loop structure of some sort to condense the code.

```
BtnList = {'Button1' : 8, 'Button2' : 3, 'Button3' : 432, 'ButtonClose' : 5004,}

for btn,ID in BtnList:
    # some code here
```

I've tried using the following outside of any loops/functions, to avoid scoping issues while testing:

```
btns = {}
btns.Button1 = Button(8)
```

But this doesn't seem to be possible as I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Button1'

Help please?

Comment: 1) `for btn,ID in BtnList` should be `for btn,ID in BtnList.items()`. 2) In Python, `btns.Button1 = Button(8)` is attribute assignment. You want `btns["Button1"] = Button(8)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with dict mapping. It should be changed to

```
btns = {}
btns["Button1"] = Button(8)
```

Then the string "Button1" inside the btns dictionary will contain the Button Object.